# Weird spikes in Loss function

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to train a U-Net on my data of shape (3,32,32,32) but my loss function has weird spikes in it that keep on decreasing. I do not understand what inference should I make from this.[image]

The code I am using is the standard training and validation routine but I am having problems in interpreting the effectiveness and the meaning of the loss plots.

Comment: To clarify some terminology, that isn’t the loss function. It is loss as a function of epoch, not as a function of the parameters. You’re training a neural network, so your loss function exists in dozens, hundreds, or billions of dimensions.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification @Dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These spikes are common, and I think that they are of no great concern.  Here is why I think they occur:

1. At the end of each epoch, most machine learning algorithms shuffle the data.
2. Most machine learning algorithms also perform gradient descent in small batches.
3. Many gradient descent algorithms have momentum terms in them.

The training gradient momentum that is built up over a few mini-batches may work very well for a while, until it hits a mini-batch which requires the model to learn something different.  Hence the spike in the error value.

Over the long run, as you can see, your errors are still decreasing.

Comment: Thank you @John L. I was wondering the same thing because the predictions are really good.